# Optimisation of error messages

Tags: c#, database-design

I was wondering what is the best way to store error message than can have above 200 characters in a database and said error message can contain diverse  parameters.

Is it better to format the message with the parameters and insert it in directly in the database

OR

store the parameters with the error code in the database and have the application determine what the message is with the error code and parameters send?

Application output:

```
Error 36 : This is a test error message that can last forever.... 
          {I might insert a date and some other parameters here...}
           and continue the endless message
```

Database side :

Case 1

```
Table ErrorMessage
ErrorCode | Message                                          
36        | This is a test error message that can last...date + RandomParameter
```

Case 2

```
Table ErrorMessage
ErrorCode | Date      | AdditionalInfo
36        | 2015-12-23| RandomParameter
```

Which would be more efficient?

**EDIT :**
These message will be searchable later on. It can be to see if a specific user got many errors and help him fix these issues or it could be an administrative error message where something was changed in the application and there was a conflict with a certain user. It will logged in the database and would need to be searchable when the user contact the administrator.

Comment: Your second option is preferred; remember the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself). If err msg 36 is always the same, just store it in one place (especially if it's long).

Comment: I think in part depends on how you're expected to use that information The lazy and easy way to do it is to just copy the entire message. That will simplify things in all fronts with the cost of a bigger table. Hopefully you're not expecting many errors to happen ;)

Comment: @B. Clay Shannon: although it's true that most of the message is the same, I believe DRY approach complicate things for most scenarios. If you show these errors on your app, then you'll have to rebuild full message. If you use a direct query on database, the message will be totally cryptic unless you go to the code and check what `36` means.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi -- I disagree. Like all good software design principals, the lesson that DRY teaches and the benefits it conveys can enhance not just your software design habits but can extend to all aspects of your life.  If you think it's complicating something, you might be looking at it from the wrong perpsective.

Comment: On a concrete level, think about what would happen if the content of the error message were to change in a substantive way -- maybe it's a legal definition, or something that could get someone sued -- you definitely only want to store it in one place.  Otherwise, you run the risk that you change one but miss another, and leave yourself open to a variety of problems.

Comment: @roryap: using any paradigm as a religious thing could be dangerous. There is no silver bullet, as I said, solution depends on how these errors will be used. IMO a DRY approach will complicate things without benefits in most scenarios for this particular problem. With your criteria of message changing, I could say that parameters could change too, making your old records useless nonetheless :)

Comment: @ClaudioRedi : Should I create a table that contains the template for the error message in case someone is using a direct query on database?

Comment: I am mainly using these "error messages" for future reference because the different parameters could vary from a comment to a monetary value.

Comment: @ThallForms: creating an extra table with templates was the only DRY approach I had in mind in case full message was not an option. That could be a good solution. In any case I believe all this discussion gave you enough information to make a decision in one direction or another. Take into account that if template changes, your old records may become useless, you're adding an extra point of failure... think if it's worth or not.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi -- Sure, your parameters could also change, but each of those is held to their own "DRY" implementation (i.e. if one parameter is used in multiple places) and is only tangentially related to the "DRY" error message at the heart of this question.  The point is, given the decision to apply dry or not to apply dry -- wherever and whenever possible -- I choose to do it, because the alternative is less desirable.  Hence, always minimize and mitigate your risk by applying good principals.

Comment: I think this is completely opinion based question (in addition to post completely missing why would you want to preserve messages part). Going with non-SQL storage and dumping searchable data like JSON may be easier (depending on goals).

Comment: Specify your needs regarding the log records. Depending on them, different ways can be "the best". E.g. if they will be searched/archived/localized/changed over time etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your points have merit. Both methods have advantages and disadvantages.

- You might store both. This gives the advantages of both, and the sole disadvantage is increased storage space.
- If you don't choose to store both, store the fully formatted message. The reason for this is if the message associated with a number changes with a new release, you may need to see the message as it was at the time it was logged.
- If you have a specific need to be able to query the parameters, then do so. But **YAGNI applies**. Don't do it just because tyou think you might in future. You can do that later by extracting them using regular expressions.

**To me, the YAGNI consideration is decisive**. Unless you have a concrete reason, today, to do anything else, do the simplest thing which meets requirements. That's probably going to be to store the full message.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the comments, reasonable people can have different opinions about this. And I think that's because it's down to interpretation.

In addition, you ask for "best", and "most efficient" - that is always a matter of context, it depends on what you want to optimize for.

However, I believe the following statements to be true.

Your application has a domain concept called "error". 
Errors have types, which can be used to categorize the error. 
Errors may have additional information which help to understand and communicate the error. 
Each error type may have different additional information.
Additional information is loosely structured - it doesn't conform to a traditional relational schema. 
For each occurrence of an error type, the content of the additional data changes, but its structure does not.

If that's all true, I'd suggest that the most "relational" model for this is:

```
ErrorTypes
------------
ErrorTypeID (PK)
ErrorTypeDescription

ErrorOccurrence
-----------------
UserID
Date
ErrorTypeID (FK)
AdditionalInformation (JSON, XML, whatever)
```